# Is it possible to listen to key presses on the lock screen?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, screen-lock

I want to have some keyboard shortcuts that work even when macOS is on the lock screen. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of defeat the purpose of a password-protected lock screen?

Comment: @nohillside Obviously not, as Apple's own iOS allows, e.g., using the camera on the lock screen.

Comment: The camera etc work in a protected mode in that case (you can't access existing pictures for instance), and Apple needed several iterations to get it right (and close the holes allowing access to the whole phone). AFAIK this functionality isn't part of macOS.